# How to get the Hash's length?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, blockchain

I'm trying to get the length of hash. Currently, I tried to make use of `len_bytes()` like in [this docs](https://docs.rs/sp-core/3.0.0/sp_core/struct.H256.html). But I encountered an error like the below image.
Please help to solve this.! Thanks in advanced.
[image]

Comment: Depending on how your pallet is configured, `T::Hash::len_bytes()` should work.

Comment: Can you make it clearer? I'm very new on this @OliverTale-Yazdi

Comment: please provide more context to your question... how is your `Hash` type configured? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: shot in the dark: try dereferencing dna: `(*dna).len_bytes()`

Comment: You dont even need an instance of the type. The length of the hash output is fixed in the type, as written above `T::Hash::len_bytes()` returns it.

Answer (score 1):

If your `T::Hash` comes from `frame_system::Config` here is the def:

```
/// The output of the `Hashing` function.
type Hash: Parameter
    + Member
    + MaybeSerializeDeserialize
    + Debug
    + MaybeDisplay
    + SimpleBitOps
    + Ord
    + Default
    + Copy
    + CheckEqual
    + sp_std::hash::Hash
    + AsRef<[u8]>
    + AsMut<[u8]>
    + MaybeMallocSizeOf
    + MaxEncodedLen;
```

Then you could simply do:

```
dna.as_ref().len()
```